# Can i fetch the list of pouplar posts of last 24 hours from Wordpress API?

Tags: rest-api

i am using wordpress api to display the posts on my flutter app where I am planning to display "Popular Posts" (Duration : Last 24 hours). How can I get the list of popular posts view in the last 24 hours time range? How can I achieve this Sort By "Popular Posts".

Comment: How do you define "popular"? WordPress does not track views, let alone views in the last 24 hours, so there would not be a way to query posts based on that. If you're using a plugin to measure post popularity, or if this is something your theme is doing, then you would need to ask the plugin/theme author.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Since i like to consume this popular posts for my flutter app, I can consume only via an API, does Wordpress plugin can send the data via API as well? I never tried Wordpress plugin's api?

Comment: Are you trying to define "popular" by "viewed on Flutter" or "viewed in WordPress"? If you are trying to sort by what's been viewed on Flutter, you'll need to see how Flutter tracks views or if you need to add functionality in Flutter. If you are trying to sort by what's been viewed in WordPress, you'll need to add functionality to WordPress, such as a plugin. Some plugins make data available through APIs, others don't, you'll need to browse and see what's available.